# Combination or Probability Word Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

Harrt and his 2 friends decided to visit a a famous wizard restaurant. In how many ways can Harry pay for their bill of 1000 pesos if he has 6 one thousand peso bills and, 4 five hundred peso bills, and 5 one hundred peso bills?

Comment: Liyah: You might learn more if you made an attempt yourself and told us about what you had tried.  Three simultaneous questions with no effort is not impressive

Answer (score 2):

Are all bills of the same denomination the same?

If they are , then the question is a case of counting different possibilites

(1,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,1,5)

i.e- 3 ways

If they are different, then we must consider the selection of the notes in each case,

6C1 + 4C2 + 4C1 = 16 ways

Comment: This is a good, relevant question, but really should be posted as a comment rather than as an answer.

Comment: I need 50 reputation to comment

Comment: Fair enough. +1.

Answer (score 0):

If Harrt gives $x$ 1000-peso bills, $y$ 500-peso bills, and $z$ 100-peso bills, then
$$1000x + 500y + 100z = 1000$$
The number of ways he can pay is the same as the number of solutions to this [Diophantine equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html), with the bounds $0 \leq x \leq 6$, $0 \leq y \leq 4$, and $0 \leq z \leq 5$ because he can give only so many bills.